# Question about the proof required for demonstrating closure of the set: $C = \{a\in G : \forall x \in G, \ (a \circ x)^2=(x \circ a)^2 \}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group.

Let $C = \{a\in G : \forall x \in G, \ (a \circ x)^2=(x \circ a)^2 \}$

In the process of demonstrating that this set satisfies closure, I get a little...uneasy...regarding how I go about proving it. I will first show my proof and then explain my queasiness.

Let $p,q \in C$ and $k \in G$

The goal is to show the following: $((p \circ q) \circ k)^2 = (k \circ (p \circ q))^2$

---

So, consider the composition...and associativity of:

$(p \circ (q \circ k))^2$

if we let $q \circ k = y$ we have:

$(p \circ y)^2$

We know that $p \in C$ and therefore:

$(p \circ y)^2 = (y \circ p)^2$

Returning $y$ to its original expression:

$(p \circ (q \circ k))^2 = ((q \circ k) \circ p)^2$

By associativity:

$((q \circ k) \circ p)^2=(q \circ (k \circ p))^2$

if we let $k \circ p = z$ we have:

$(q \circ z)^2$

We know that $q \in C$ and therefore:

$(q \circ z)^2=(z \circ q)^2$

Returning $z$ to its original form:

$(q \circ (k \circ p))^2 = ((k \circ p) \circ q)^2$

Therefore:

$(p \circ (q \circ k))^2 = ((k \circ p) \circ q)^2$

And with associativity:

$((p \circ q) \circ k)^2 = (k \circ (p \circ q))^2$, which is what we sought out to prove.

---

So, okay. I think I demonstrated that this set exhibits closure. What troubles me, though, is that, generally, $z \neq y$.

When I claimed at the beginning that $p,q \in C$, what I really mean is that:

1. $(p \circ x)^2 = (x \circ p)^2$
2. $(q \circ x)^2 = (x \circ q)^2$

i.e. ***between the two equations***, there is a correspondence between the $\forall $ variable...specifically, $x$

However: later in the proof, I generate the following 2 equations:

1. $(p \circ y)^2 = (y \circ p)^2$
2. $(q \circ z)^2=(z \circ q)^2$

*where, generally, $y\neq z$*

In this case, ***between the two equations***, there is no longer a correspondance between the $\forall$ variable.

Is this a logical issue? Or does it only matter that, ***within the equations***, the $\forall$ variables are consistent?

Comment: The quantification occurs for **each** term. That is, $p$ has the property that *for all $x\in G$*, $(px)^2 = (xp)^2$. And separately, $q$ has the property that *for all $x\in G$, $(qx)^2 = (xq)^2$. These are two separate statements, and the quantifications are independent. You could just as well write the second equation as "for all $t\in G$, $(qt)^2 = (tq)^2$". In short, what you did is right. There are two quantifications, independent of each other, not a single one, in your assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual question is answered in a comment, but note that the statement can be generalized and the proof is similar.

Let $G$ be any group and let $f : G \rightarrow S$ be any function, where $S$ is a set. Then $$C_f = \{ a \in G : f(ax) = f(xa) \text { for all } x \in G \}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Clearly the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is always contained in $C_f$. Conversely if $Z(G) \leq H \leq G$, is it true that $H = C_f$ for some map $f$?